# Animate element to random left position

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using this code to generate random left position of an element and animate it to that position.

```
function moveBox() {

    var randomSpeed = Math.round(Math.random()*200);
    var bounceSpeed = defaultSpeed + randomSpeed;   

    var randomX = Math.round(Math.random()*200);

    $("#box").animate({left:'"+='+randomX+'"', top:"+=20"},bounceSpeed, "linear", function(){moveBox();});
};
```

However its not working for some reason. The top animation works flawlessly because its just normal number. But the left property doesnt do anything, I think its something with the method i added the += and "" but cant figure out how to fix it.

Comment: `defaultSpeed` is not defined anywhere in your example.

Answer (score 3):

You messed the quotes.

Supposing `randomX` is `44`, you're building the `"+=44"` string instead of `+=44`, that is your string contains quotes.

Change

```
$("#box").animate({left:'"+='+randomX+'"', top:"+=20"},bounceSpeed, "linear", function(){moveBox();});
```

to

```
$("#box").animate({left:'+='+randomX, top:"+=20"},bounceSpeed, "linear", function(){moveBox();});
```